# Como enviar um objeto de uma página para outras sem nodejs

Tags: jquery, socket

Minha dúvida é a seguinte sei que existe o nodejs para fazer a conexão de servers para clientes.

Como eu consigo fazer com que a partir de uma página enviar um objeto tipo json para outra.

Seria algo emit client to client

Resolvi com peerjs

Vou deixa o site pra quem precisar http://peerjs.com

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo? As páginas seriam entre utilizadores diferentes ou queres passar o objeto navegando no site?

Comment: A ideia é que uma pagina possa ser o servidor que faz a consulta no db quando tiver algo novo ele mande para uma segunda pagina que é o cliente, eu disse client to client, pq se alguém tiver uma solução eu consigo implementar para o que eu preciso.

Comment: Rafael Antunes, podes utilizar Ajax para isso.